# What is the correct pattern for a vector of structs where each struct contains a subset of an array of structs?

Tags: vector, rust, lifetime

I've got code very similar to the following (my filter function is more complex though):

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
    count: i32,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn filter(&self) -> bool {
        return self.a > self.b + self.count;
    }
}
struct ContainerStruct<'a> {
    x: i32,
    v: Vec<&'a MyStruct>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut list_of_items = vec![
        MyStruct {
            a: 1,
            b: 2,
            count: 0,
        },
        MyStruct {
            a: 2,
            b: 1,
            count: 0,
        },
        MyStruct {
            a: 5,
            b: 2,
            count: 0,
        },
    ];
    let mut count = 0;
    let mut list_of_containers: Vec<ContainerStruct> = Vec::new();
    while count < 10 {
        let mut c = ContainerStruct {
            x: 1,
            v: Vec::new(),
        };

        for i in list_of_items.iter_mut() {
            i.count = count;
            if i.filter() {
                c.v.push(i);
            }
        }
        count += 1;
        list_of_containers.push(c)
    }
}
```

Which does not compile, due to the following error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `list_of_items` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:43:18
   |
43 |         for i in list_of_items.iter_mut() {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of loop
```

I know this is a borrow-checking issue, and I can see the potential problems with references etc.  What I don't know is the correct pattern to use to achieve what I'm looking for, which is essentially a vector of structs, where each struct contains a subset of an array of structs.

I need to be able to mutate the structs, so I'm forced into using `iter_mut()`.

However that moves the vector into that scope which then gets released next time I go through the external while loop.

Is there any way to force the vector to live long enough to complete the outer loop?  I thought about copying the structs but I don't want to do that.  I only need references to each one and copying would introduce an unacceptable overhead due to the size of the vector in question.

Comment: Two of the three errors are unrelated to lifetimes: Just put a "mut" before the variables like the compiler suggests.

Comment: `i.count = count;` what is suppose to do this ? you want only one copy of your struct so what is the point to erase previous count each time you loop ?

Comment: See this example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aea6636da498a57f03e8898fab931bd0

Comment: Or this [other example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a17429ccc71110aaeb9b7c95d0585186), using `Cell` for the mutable part:

Comment: In the end, can an item end up in several containers, or should each item be added to a single container? If the latter, you could move the items out of `list_of_items` when you add them to a container (see also [`drain_filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain_filter)).

Comment: Thanks guys, tidied up those two mut errors (was rushing out the house when I wrote this).  Those examples do compile so thank you, I'll do some reading around to understand how they work

Comment: Why is `count` part of `MyStruct` at all, instead of just being an argument to `filter`? If you're using `list_of_containers` to access structs, you already have the `count` -- it's just the index into `list_of_containers`. Storing a thing's index in a container inside the thing itself is often (but not always) unnecessary; do you really need it or are you just using it for the algorithm? [Here's what I'm imagining.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d374a71d2613a025573a552c0c1a772e)

Comment: in truth the filter algorithm is much more complex, and also proprietary.  Also there are calculations later on that require that value to be stored as well.  I'll consider the option you're suggesting because it might be possible to restructure the code to not store these variables actually.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles:

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;

struct MyStruct {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
    count: Cell<i32>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn filter(&self) -> bool {
        return self.a > self.b + self.count.get();
    }
}
struct ContainerStruct<'a> {
    x: i32,
    v: Vec<&'a MyStruct>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut list_of_items = vec![
        MyStruct {
            a: 1,
            b: 2,
            count: Cell::new(0),
        },
        MyStruct {
            a: 2,
            b: 1,
            count: Cell::new(0),
        },
        MyStruct {
            a: 5,
            b: 2,
            count: Cell::new(0),
        },
    ];
    let mut count = 0;
    let mut list_of_containers: Vec<ContainerStruct> = Vec::new();
    while count < 10 {
        let mut c = ContainerStruct {
            x: 1,
            v: Vec::new(),
        };

        for i in list_of_items.iter() {
            i.count.set(count);
            if i.filter() {
                c.v.push(i);
            }
        }
        count += 1;
        list_of_containers.push(c)
    }
}
```